# Using safeAreaLayoutGuide without status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, padding

I am adding all of my views programmatically as well as their auto layout constraints. In one of my views I have disabled the status bar using this:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Apparently this causes the safeAreaLayoutGuide to be moved by 20px on anything that isn't the iPhone X. And in my case this results in not having enough padding at top for the iPhone 6/7/8/SE etc.

What's the cleanest way to work around this? How would you add padding e.g. on the iPhone 8 views without adding it to the iPhone X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the status bar transparent to keep the space instead of using `prefersStatusBarHidden`. In terms of spacing this will have no effect on iPhone X.

```
let statusBarWindow = application.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as? UIWindow
statusBarWindow.alpha = 0.0
```

`"statusBarWindow"` is actually private API, so better pull it apart like `"status" + "BarWindow"` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might use the following solution:
start creating a custom view (let's call it fakeStatusBar) which should match the status bar frame, having these constraints:

### [image]

Please note that height = 20 is not enough, since status bar height is depending by your device (iPhone 8 plus is = 20, iPhoneX is > 20), so you have to change dynamically doing so:

[image]

```
self.fakeStatusBarHeight.constant = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height // or whatever you like, considering your padding too
```

So at this step we have a good space thanks to the fakeStatusBar, then let's constraint your inner view doing so (of course height = 40 is just an example):

[image]

The final result is:

**iPhoneX**

[image]

**iPhone 8 plus:**

[image]